# downloading the last 48 hours of facebook news feed

Tags: facebook, caching

One my friends died a few days ago and the family is trying to download their news feed since the posts started(roughly **48 hours** ago).

Does anyone know of a way to download the news feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's impossible. Data changes every second, and the connections of objects (comments, likes) would be late on your files. Also, that information is not yours, and is not correct to "download" it. I think you should make a video, maybe thats the best solluction for remembering this date on the future. If you save the files of the news feed, the files will be unreadable .......... and the data will be lost in a big messy of code .